# Print Table and Chart in Same Document Using jsPDF-Autotable

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

How would I print both a chart or image and a table, using jspdf-autotable?
Let's say I have a chart and I want to put that right before the table.
Or I have some HTML text customized by a client and I need to combine it with a small table right below the custom HTML.
I tried to increase the top margin to open space to the image inserted, it kinda worked.
But what if I don't know the size of the element I'll have to insert before or after the table?

```js
  async printThisThingsTogether() {
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm','a4');
    const marginsParent = { top: 105, bottom: 35, left: 15, right: 15 };
    doc.setFontSize(5);
    doc.setPage(1);

    var coolCanvas = document.getElementById('coolCanvas')! as HTMLCanvasElement;
    var newCanvasImg = coolCanvas!.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0)!;
    doc.addImage(newCanvasImg, 'PNG', 10, 10, 190, 90 );

    let page = document.getElementById(`table`) as HTMLTableElement;
    autoTable(doc, {
      html: page,
      margin: marginsParent,
      useCss: false,
      theme: 'plain',
      styles: {
        lineColor: [44, 62, 80],
        lineWidth: 1,
      },
      headStyles: {
        fillColor: [241, 196, 15],
        fontSize: 15,
      },
      footStyles: {
        fillColor: [241, 196, 15],
        fontSize: 15,
      },
      bodyStyles: {
        fillColor: [52, 73, 94],
        textColor: 240,
      },
      alternateRowStyles: {
        fillColor: [74, 96, 117],
      },
    });
    await doc.output('dataurlnewwindow', {filename: 'listagem.pdf'});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put chart/image/html content above the table, you should set `startY` of the autoTable which refers to starting Y point of the table.

If you want to put non-table content below the table then you should get the the Y point where the table ends via
`doc.lastAutoTable.finalY` in which *doc* refers the jsPDF instance. Then put the content with respect to that.

Hope it helps.

Cheers